Why Are User Reviews in the Admin Panel Showing Identical Content but Different IDs and Dates?
I'm encountering an issue with my Laravel admin panel where user reviews are duplicated with different IDs and dates. The same review content (title, body, author name) appears multiple times but with distinct review IDs and submission dates.
Example:
Review titled "Great App!" by User A appears twice with different IDs (123 and 456) and dates (June 1st and June 15th).
Code Snippet:
//Reviews fetched from the App Store using a scheduled task (up to 200 reviews/hour)
public function fetchReviews($token, $appId)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    $headers = array(
        "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Authorization: Bearer " . $token
    );

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/apps/$appId/customerReviews?include=response&sort=-createdDate&limit=200",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60
    ));

    $curlResponse = curl_exec($curl);
    $result = json_decode($curlResponse);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}

//Store fetched reviews into the database
public function storeReviewsInDB($appId, $reviews)
{
    $customerReviews = $reviews->data ?? [];
    $app = DB::select('SELECT id, name FROM apps WHERE app_store_id = ?', [$appId]);
    $appId = $app[0]->id;

    $lastInsertedDate = DB::select(
        'SELECT review_submitted_at FROM reviews WHERE app_id = ? ORDER BY review_submitted_at DESC LIMIT 1',
        [$appId]
    );
    $lastDate = $lastInsertedDate[0]->review_submitted_at ?? null;

    $insertData = [];
    foreach ($customerReviews as $customerReview) {
        $reviewSubmittedAt = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($customerReview->attributes->createdDate));

        if (is_null($lastDate) || $reviewSubmittedAt > $lastDate) {
            $responseId = $customerReview->relationships->response->data->id ?? null;
            $insertData[] = [
                'app_id' => $appId,
                'review_id' => $customerReview->id,
                'author_name' => $customerReview->attributes->reviewerNickname,
                'title' => $customerReview->attributes->title,
                'body' => $customerReview->attributes->body,
                'rating' => $customerReview->attributes->rating,
                'country' => $customerReview->attributes->territory,
                'review_submitted_at' => $reviewSubmittedAt,
                'response_id' => $responseId
            ];
        }
    }

    if (!empty($insertData)) {
        DB::table('reviews')->insert($insertData);
    }
}

Problems:

Duplicate Reviews: Identical content appears multiple times.
Different IDs and Dates: Each entry has a different review ID and date.

What I Have Tried:

Checked database queries and insertion logic without finding obvious issues.
Verified API response to ensure reviews are not duplicated at the source.

Desired Behavior:

Each review should be stored only once in the database.
Avoid duplicate entries even if fetched multiple times from the API.

Request for Help:
Has anyone faced this problem or has suggestions to resolve it? How can I ensure each review is stored only once?
Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

My guess is the date string comparison $reviewSubmittedAt > $lastDate is not behaving as you expect, that would explain duplicates.  What format is $lastDate in?  Play it safe, compare the timestamps.  Also fetchReviews() does not do anything with the fetched reviews, nor return them - this can't be your real code?

Thank you for your observation! Could you please explain how this issue might occur? The format of $lastDate is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.
Regarding the fetchReviews() function, I understand that it appears incomplete in the snippet I provided. In the actual implementation, it correctly handles the received reviews. I apologize for any confusion caused by the partial example.
I appreciate your feedback and will make the necessary adjustments.
Thanks again for your input!
